# Make a sliding sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to create a sliding sidebar in a website so when a user moves over the right hand side of the page (lets say the 15% of the main content area), the pane moves to the left and shows a map of a area and move back when the user moves away from the area. It would also have a link to google maps so it well include a  tag as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*.animate()*](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) in jQuery, but you seem that you need to watch or follow some examples. I think that this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzVFB3Ba_o)  is a good start.

Also have a [look](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_animate.asp) on .animate() basic use.
Another [good guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-jquery-animate-method/).

I hope that helps, good luck.

Comment: Personally I'm not big on javescript writing and most of the time I have a friend who would normally help me on this. I have been trying to find some examples though they all seem to use the 'hamburger' or three lines as an activator for the hidden menu.